# JPA (with EclipseLink) Performance issue

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have just started using JPA (with EclipseLink implementation). I have a very simply select query, like

(1) entityManager.find(SomeEntity.class, SomeEntityPK);
(2) entityManager.createQuery("Select x from SomeEntity x where x.isDefault = true").getResultList();

The number of records in SomeEntity table is approx 50 (very small table).

Query (1) initially takes 3s, but subsequent hit just takes 200ms. Obviously cache is at play.
However Query (2) takes 2s for all invocations- wonder why cache is not used. I understand Query (those not using Id or Index) always hits DB and Entity relationships are utilized from Cache.

Is there any way to improve the performance? A simple JDBC select just takes <300ms to fetch data for Query (2).

[UPDATE]
I think I have solved the issue. One of the columbs in table 'SomeEntity' was Oracle XMLType. Due to some issue, I had to remove this field and instead use a CLOB field to store xml data. and voila, JPA suddenly started caching the query result. Although I don't know reason why JPA doesn't caches XMLType.

Comment: entityManager API(find,merge...) performs differently with custom query. entityManager will always try to look up the entity from persistence context. it only looks into DB when the entity is not found int persistence context. Once the entity instance is loaded into persistence context, it gets cached until transaction committed or manually flush persistence context. That is why the second query is much faster. Custom query will by pass the persistence context cache to interact with DB every time.

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink has a number of caches at different levels that can be used.  I think the query cache is what you might be looking for described here 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/core.1111/e10108/toplink.htm#BCGEGHGE
And explained a bit here 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Queries_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Cache_Query_Results_in_the_Query_Cache